# Laptop randomly crashes after removing its inflated battery

Tags: laptop, battery, crash

I noticed that my laptop OMEN by HP 15-dc0044nf was open under it, so I opened it and saw that the battery was inflated. I removed the battery and since then my laptop just randomly crashes.

While browsing the internet I notice that there is no sound anymore. When I try to click the Windows logo it doesn't work.

Sometimes explorer.exe crashes.  I  usually see a message "ctfmon.exe stopped working" and then near 10 seconds after I notice all this, my laptop crashes.

This never happened before I removed the battery.

Since I never use this laptop with its battery, I don't want to spend money on a new one I will never use.

I don't think it's because the power cable becomes loose or something. I taped it and sometimes it crashes without me even moving.

Some days it never crashes, while other days it crashes 2 times in a row. It did crash while I was writing this and also 20 minutes ago.

I asked this first on the HP forum and they just said that it's probably a hardware issue, but I have no warranty anymore. All calls are paid so I am seeking help here before doing a paid call

PC Information:
OMEN by HP 15-dc0044nf,
Windows 10 Pro 21H2 64 bits.
All updates installed, there is no new BIOS versions when I check HP website

Comment: The first thing to consider is that no matter how on its last legs your battery was, it was still doing its job to some extent. Its job is to power your computer. The charger's job is to *charge the battery*. When you remove the battery sometimes the charger can't keep up, so you get random crashes.

Comment: You might also consider taking it to a local shop for an assessment about possible repairs.

Comment: @Tetsujin i know that but the battery was inflated, it's was dangerous to keep it and i threw it

Comment: A swollen battery may cause irregular electrical current, which may cause problems with other components. A repair-shop will be able to diagnose such problems.

Comment: The crashes and battery removal are likely unrelated _(coincidence doesn't equal correlation)_. While plugged in, a laptop doesn't run off the battery, however the battery does act to absorb any current spikes. **Do not use your battery again**, take it to a business that recycles NiCad/Li-Ion batteries  _(do not place the battery in a battery recycle box because it's compromised from damage)_, and until you can, store it in a non-flammable area that will not cause a fire should it catch fire - 18650s burn at ~2000F _(18650s are the battery cells used in rechargeable lithium battery packs)_.

Comment: @Tetsujin Your comment is factually inaccurate - while plugged in, a laptop's battery simply acts to absorb current fluctuations _(why it's not recommended to run a laptop without a battery)_, as the purpose of the charger is to power the laptop _**and**_ charge the battery. An OEM charger will always cover the max wattage of a laptop, except when equipped with a discrete GPU, in which case the OEM usually will offer two chargers, a standard and higher wattage one; if a laptop draws more wattage than the charger can provide w/o a battery installed, it wouldn't crash, it would simply turn off

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities here:

1. The bloated battery put pressure on the inside of the laptop with resulted in loose contacts somewhere in the internals after the pressure was removed when you took the battery out.  This would be a rare thing and very unlikely in my opinion, but I cant rule it out. If it is the case the laptop is probably beyond repair.
2. The more likely situation is that with the battery removed small random spikes in the power-grid are getting through unfiltered and they are bad enough to cause stability issues. In that case you have 2 options: Get a new battery or put a UPS (essentially an external battery) between the laptop and the power-outlet on the wall. (An UPS may actaully be cheaper than a new battery.)